# How to apply Material Theme to all buttons in application (activity)?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, android-theme, material-components-android

I'm trying to customize my Android theme, but nothing seems to work.

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
}
```

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Delete" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.App.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.Button</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.Button" parent="" >
        <!-- For filled buttons, your theme's colorPrimary provides the default background color of the component-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In layout I'm using **Material Design Components** for example

```
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_home_all"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/home_all"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

but the default `purple_200` background color is applied to the button. Can you help me a bit? I read that there I should use `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity` but I can't change it as my activity is a bottom navigation activity I can't find support for `onSupportNavigateUp` or other realated stuff

### EDIT

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="licenta.allbank">

 
    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AllBank" 
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="callback"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you include your manifest where you've set the theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. If you're testing on your phisical device and it is set on **dark mode**, you should make the changes in your `values-night/themes.xml` file, otherwise, working on your `values/themes.xml` should be enough

Answer (score 1):

To use a `MaterialButton` you have to use a [`Theme.MaterialComponents.*`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes) theme in your app.

Then you can define the [**`materialButtonStyle`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md#theming-all-instances-of-one-component) attribute.

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    ....

    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button</item>
  </style>
```

In this way you can customize the theme of all the buttons in your app.

To override the default background color you can use the **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute:

```
  <style name="Widget.App.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
     <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.Button</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ThemeOverlay.Button" parent="" >
    <!-- For filled buttons, your theme's colorPrimary provides the default background color of the component-->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_color</item>        
  </style>
```

Otherwise you can use the **`backgroundTint`** attribute in your custom style:

```
<style name="Widget.App.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <!-- Background color --> 
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/buttonBackgroundSelector</item>
</style>
```

Comment: In the Layout editor, it shows the custom color, but when running the app on my phone, it's the default color

Comment: @AndreiManolache Does your Activity or App use the theme with the materialButtonStyle attribute?